# Json type mismatch: Cannot convert to string

Tags: java, android, json

I am developing a program that is posting to a server and retrieves a json object and then converts it to a String array.

When I test the result on my browser I get the following result:

```
{"Bookname":["Alive-O","All Write Now ","Bun Go Barr 1","Planet Maths","Small World"],"SubjectName":["Religion","English","Irish","Maths","Science"]}
```

Here's my class where I post and convert the string:

```
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://cosy.azurewebsites.net/bookrequest.php");

    User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();

    String username = user.username;

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair( "Username", username ));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


    String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Bookname");
    BookName = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        BookName[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
    }

    // for getting subjectnames
    Log.v("we're getting a subject", "2");

    jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("SubjectName");
    BookSubject = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        BookSubject[i] = jsonArray.getString(i);
    }

}
```

Here is what my log cat is telling me:

```
02-21 18:15:35.538    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-21 18:15:35.538    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
02-21 18:15:35.538    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
02-21 18:15:35.538    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
02-21 18:15:35.538    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at net.azurewebsites.cosy.Books$getBooks.doInBackground(Books.java:148)
02-21 18:15:35.538    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at net.azurewebsites.cosy.Books$getBooks.doInBackground(Books.java:106)
02-21 18:15:35.538    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-21 18:15:35.538    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-21 18:15:35.542    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-21 18:15:35.542    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-21 18:15:35.542    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-21 18:15:35.542    1436-3694/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am trying to get this to then use as an array in class.

Comment: What line are you getting the error?

Comment: @Majora320 String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result); is the line

Comment: OK, so it's what @DeveloperXy said

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you are trying to convert a `JSONArray` to a `JSONObject`, which means that this instruction:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

is problematic. There is a very good chance that the JSON you get is surrounded by brackets (since you tested it in a browser, not on your mobile device). Try changing:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

to

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject jsonObject = obj.getJSONObject(0);
```

Comment: I did that and it fixed that error and is now saying org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)

Comment: That means that the response you're getting from the server is an empty `JSONArray` **([ ])**. Please confirm my theory by logging the response you get to the logcat.

Comment: you are right response is [] which is very strange I know what's being posted is correct so I'm not sure why it is happening

Comment: @EoinÓCribín In that case, you gonna have to make sure to establish a successful connection to the server.

Comment: Fixed getting a result the post was a capital letter (silly mistake) Though I am getting the same error it won't convert here's the result: 02-21 18:52:03.643 1478-1523/net.azurewebsites.cosy W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value {"Bookname":["Alive-O","All Write Now ","Bun Go Barr 1","Planet Maths","Small World"],"SubjectName":["Religion","English","Irish","Maths","Science"]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray